# Make Text align in center of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am unable to align the text. **I want to show it in the center of the image circle.**
Right now the text just hovers above the image.

I am using the `text-align:center;` declaration.
But I guess I am missing something.

Here is my code snippet:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Center the "info" bubble in the  "circle" div
    var divTop = ($("#divCircle").height() - $("#middleBubble").height()) / 2;
    var divLeft = ($("#divCircle").width() - $("#middleBubble").width()) / 2;
    $("#middleBubble").css("top", divTop + "px");
    $("#middleBubble").css("left", divLeft + "px");

    //Arrange the icons in a circle centered in the div
    numItems = $("#divCircle img").length; //How many items are in the circle?
    start = 0.25; //the angle to put the first image at. a number between 0 and 2pi
    step = (2 * Math.PI) / numItems; //calculate the amount of space to put between the items.

    //Now loop through the buttons and position them in a circle
    $("#divCircle img").each(function(index) {
      radius = ($("#divCircle").width() - $(this).width()) / 2; //The radius is the distance from the center of the div to the middle of an icon
      //the following lines are a standard formula for calculating points on a circle. x = cx + r * cos(a); y = cy + r * sin(a)
      //We have made adjustments because the center of the circle is not at (0,0), but rather the top/left coordinates for the center of the div
      //We also adjust for the fact that we need to know the coordinates for the top-left corner of the image, not for the center of the image.
      tmpTop = (($("#divCircle").height() / 2) + radius * Math.sin(start)) - ($(this).height() / 2);
      tmpLeft = (($("#divCircle").width() / 2) + radius * Math.cos(start)) - ($(this).width() / 2);
      start += step; //add the "step" number of radians to jump to the next icon

      //set the top/left settings for the image
      $(this).css("top", tmpTop);
      $(this).css("left", tmpLeft);
    });

    //set the highlight and bubble default based on the homepageGridDefault class
    currentGridSelector = $(".homepageGridDefault").attr("id");
    $("#" + currentGridSelector).attr("src", "images/home-" + currentGridSelector + "-icon-on.png");
    $("#middleBubble").html("<p><b>" + $(".homepageGridDefault").data("bubble1") + "</b><br />" + $(".homepageGridDefault").data("bubble2") + "</p>");

    //Setup the grid to change the highlighted bubble on mouseover ans click
    $("#divCircle img").mouseover(function() {
      //if the selected option has changed, deactivate the current selection
      if (currentGridSelector != $(this).attr("id")) {
        $("#" + currentGridSelector).attr("src", "images/home-" + currentGridSelector + "-icon-off.png");
      }
      //turn on the new selection
      $(this).attr("src", "images/home-" + $(this).attr("id") + "-icon-on.png");
      //set the content of the center bubble
      $("#middleBubble").html("<p><b>" + $(this).data("bubble1") + "</b><br />" + $(this).data("bubble2") + "</p>");
      currentGridSelector = $(this).attr("id");
    });
  });
```

```css
/**
 *
 * Position icons into circle (SO)
 * 
 */

#mainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#divCircle {
  width: 485px;
  height: 485px;
  position: relative;
}
#divCircle img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 18%;
  height: 18%;
}
#middleBubble {
  position: realtive;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: url(../img/circle/9.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
}
#middleBubble b {
  font-size: 1em;
}
#middleBubble p {
  margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
      <div class="center-block" id="divCircle">
        <div id="middleBubble">&nbsp;</div>

        <img class="img-circle" src="img/circle/home-all-icon-off.png" id="all" data-bubble1="all:" data-bubble2="discounted lab work<br />on-site">

        <img class="img-circle" src="img/circle/home-cover-icon-off.png" id="cover" data-bubble1="Lorem cover<br />personalized<br />lorem:" data-bubble2="Lorem Ipsum,<br />Ipsim Lorem, lore, lorem">

        <img class="img-circle" src="img/circle/home-diy-icon-off.png" id="diy" data-bubble1="diy:" data-bubble2="Lorem Ipsum,<br />Ipsim Lorem, lore, lorem">

        <img class="img-circle" src="img/circle/home-marketing-icon-off.png" id="marketing" data-bubble1="marketing:" data-bubble2="Lorem Ipsum,<br />Ipsim Lorem, lore, lorem">

        <img class="img-circle" src="img/circle/home-other-icon-off.png" id="other" data-bubble1="other plans:" data-bubble2="Lorem Ipsum,<br />Ipsim Lorem, lore, lorem">

        <img class="img-circle" src="img/circle/home-special-icon-off.png" id="special" data-bubble1="special for you:" data-bubble2="Lorem Ipsum,<br />Ipsim Lorem, lore, lorem">

        <img class="img-circle" src="img/circle/home-vip-icon-off.png" id="vip" data-bubble1="you are Vip:" data-bubble2="Lorem Ipsum,<br />Ipsim Lorem, lore, lorem">

        <img class="img-circle" src="img/circle/home-designe-icon-off.png" id="designe" data-bubble1: "designe from us:" data-bubble2="Lorem Ipsum,<br />Ipsim Lorem, lore, lorem">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am still not sure what you want, try with `#middleBubble p{
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top:50%;
}`

Comment: you want to show message at the center of each image? or only one image as in jsfiddle?

Comment: in the center of this fiddle should be an message bubble and in that bubble I want to display text, but mine text is hovering on top off an image, when I display it, it is not in the center

Comment: I have found the solution, @user2688337 thank for the hint, it is centered now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with your sample, and made it (perhaps) work based on what I think you're trying to achieve.  Sorry if I misunderstood.  The jsfiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/6s5h1dar/1/

Essentially I modified your code using help from this page:

http://howtocenterincss.com/

Modified HTML:

```
<div id="bubbleWrap">
    <div id="middleBubble">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Modified CSS:

```
#bubbleWrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 485px;
    width: 485px;
}

#middleBubble {
    background: url(../img/circle/9.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #252525;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Does that suit your needs?

Comment: I have solved mine problem earlier, but nevertheless I can use this example to learn something, thank you, and yes is the answer to your question.

Comment: @Idiomatic glad to hear you've solved the problem independently.  As a suggestion - you may want to update your original question with your solution.  This will help future readers of the question.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Centering in general can be difficult with HTML/CSS. A good primer on all the good ways to do it is located on css-tricks.com here:

https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

For your specific situation adding

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -65px; // height of the box
```

Would do the trick, but using a flex box or another more complicated trick (outlined as css-tricks) would allow you to avoid the brittle margin-top hack, which limits centering to a specific number of lines.

Comment: Apparently I did not put this wright, I have centered mine image, whit bootstrap class, but the text I want to display in that image is the problem, it is hovering above mine centered image, I want it in the image, thanks for the answer.